# Vandermonde matrix DG Hestaven

Tags: interpolation, quadrature, discontinuous-galerkin

I am trying to understand the nodal and modal basis formulation from the book of Hesthaven ([Nodal Discontinuous Galerkin Methods, Hesthaven, Jan S., Warburton, Tim](http://springer.com/gp/book/9780387720654)). For $N=2$, I get the Vandermonde Matrix, which is computed by the Jacobi polynomial for $\alpha, \beta =0$ which is the Legendre polynomial:

```
V = Vandermonde1D(2, x)

V =

0.7071   -1.2247    1.5811
0.7071         0   -0.7906
0.7071    1.2247    1.5811
```

and `x = (-1,0,1)` the LGL points.

In the book on page 48, it says that for $N=6$ the d) option on the table is for orthonormal basis with Legendre-Gauss-Lobatto points.

Now, if I run a code [from here](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4775-legende-gauss-lobatto-nodes-and-weights?focused=5055264&tab=function)

```
[x,w,P]=lglnodes(2)
```

I get

```
x =
-1
 0
 1
```

which are the LGL points and

```
w =
0.3333
1.3333
0.3333
```

the weights.
But then I get

```
P =
1.0000   -1.0000    1.0000
1.0000   -0.0000   -0.5000
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
```

In the comments for the program, it says

> Computes the Legendre-Gauss-Lobatto nodes, weights, and the LGL Vandermonde matrix. The LGL nodes are the zeros of $(1-x^2)P'_N(x)$

But this is different than the Vandermonde I get from the original program of Hesthaven.

Now, I kinda understand what this $P$ Matrix is.
If you have the [Legendre Polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials)

$p_{0}(x) = 1,  p_{1}(x) = x, p_{2}(x) = \frac{1}{2}(3x^{2} -1)$.

and replace the LGL points `(-1,0,1)` I get this $P$ matrix.
But how to get the Vandermonde matrix?

Comment: What is the "book of Hesthaven"? Do you have a full bibliographic reference?

Comment: Nodal Discontinuous Galerkin Methods,  Hesthaven, Jan S., Warburton, Tim
http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387720654

Comment: You can add it as a part of your question

Comment: Isn't the difference just the constant gamma that Westhaven and Warburton include that the Matlab code doesn't?

Comment: you mean on the JacobiP file for the Jacobi Polynomial?
can you be more specific?

Comment: Hesthaven and Warburton define the orthonormal basis as psi(r) = P_(n-1)(r)/gamma(n-1)  (see page 45 of the book for clarity, as I can't format the maths in a comment), where as the Matlab code use psi(r)  = P_(n-1)(r) as the basis function, where in both cases P_n(r) is the nth Legendre Polynomial. So as far I can tell the difference you're seeing is simply due to the use of a different basis function, which happen to be different only by a constant (the gamma(n) term) on the individual functions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the "normalized" Legendre Polynomials instead of Legendre Polynomials. Where you divide the Legendre polynomial by $\sqrt{\frac{2}{2n+1}}$.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the orthonormalized version of the Legendre polynomials, while Hesthaven is not. The polynomials in your matrix are normalized by a factor of $\sqrt{\frac{2n+1}{2}}$, i.e. $\sqrt{\frac{2(1)+1}{2}}=1.2247$ and $\sqrt{\frac{2(2)+1}{2}}=1.5811$.